# Dart call reoccuring function through timer

Tags: dart

I want to call this function for every 60 seconds

```
var strStream = _customUrl.getStreamData(fixtureId);
```

For that I had wrote a code like this

```
const sixtySec = const Duration(seconds:60);
new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => _customUrl.getStreamData(fixtureId));
```

But this timer function won't give the output to "strStream" variable. Is there any way to get the timer output to my variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but it sounds like what you want is the following?

```
new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => strStream = _customUrl.getStreamData(fixtureId));
```

If not, please give more details with a more complete example showing what you want.